# Return a list of string using LINQ through a loop of conditionals

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class named **Skill** and I received a list of it through a parameter and I need to create a list of strings by LINQ that has some rules.

My Class

```
public class Skill {
        public int id {get;set;}
        public int year {get;set;}
        public int xp {get;set;}
    }
```

Dummy data:

```
var skills = new List<Skill>(){
            new Skill() { id=1, year = 9, xp = 95 } ,
            new Skill() { id=2, year = 5 } ,
        };
```

Rules:
// year goes at max 10
// xp goes at max 100

The list of strings I must create is like this:
for each year until 10 plus xp until 100 (if has)

```
    // '1-9-95'
    // '1-9-96'
    // '1-9-97'
    // '1-9-98'
    // '1-9-99'
    // '1-9-99'
    // '1-9-100'
    // '1-10-95'
    // '1-10-96'
    // '1-10-97'
    // '1-10-98'
    // '1-10-99'
    // '1-10-99'
    // '1-10-100'
    // '2-5'
    // '2-6'
    // '2-7'
    // '2-8'
    // '2-9'
    // '2-10'
```

I got it using **for** statement, but I was wondering about using LINQ.

Comment: Why is 1-9-99 and 1-10-99 both in there twice?  Also why are you not doing 2-5-0; 2-5-1, ..., 2-5-10?  Honestly if you have a for loop that works I don't think translating to a Linq solution will gain you anything.  It will not be faster and likely will be harder to read.

Comment: Why don't you share the for loop? So we could see and tell how to improve or LINQify it. IMHO it would help.

Comment: What does "year goes at max 10" mean exactly?

Comment: Try following :            string[] results = skills.SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(x.year, 11 - x.year).SelectMany(y => (x.xp == 0) ? Enumerable.Range(0,1).Select(z => x.id + "-" + y) : Enumerable.Range(x.xp, 101 - x.xp).Select(z => x.id + "-" + y + "-" + z))).ToArray();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `SelectMany` and `Enumerable.Range`:

```
int maxYear = 10, maxXp = 100;
List<string> resultList = skills
    .Where(skill => skill.year <= maxYear && skill.xp <= maxXp) // skip invalid
    .SelectMany(skill => Enumerable.Range(skill.year, maxYear - skill.year + 1)
        .SelectMany(y => Enumerable.Range(skill.xp, maxXp - skill.xp + 1)
            .Select(xp => $"{skill.id}-{y}-{xp}")))
    .ToList();
```

.NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/c80wJs

I think i have overlooked that "(if has)", so you want to list xp only if available:

```
int maxYear = 10, maxXp = 100;
List<string> resultList = skills
    .Where(skill => skill.year <= maxYear && skill.xp <= maxXp) // skip invalid
    .SelectMany(skill => Enumerable.Range(skill.year, maxYear - skill.year + 1)
        .SelectMany(y => Enumerable.Range(skill.xp, skill.xp == 0 ? 1 : maxXp - skill.xp + 1)
            .Select(xp => skill.xp > 0 ? $"{skill.id}-{y}-{xp}" : $"{skill.id}-{y}")))
    .ToList();
```

.NET-fiddle for this (thanks to Rand Random): https://dotnetfiddle.net/06BIqg

Comment: I believe you are missing that `xp` shouldn't be printed if it is 0. From OPs sample output data eg. `'2-5'`

Comment: @RandRandom: I just implemented what he has explained. Maybe he can clarify the requirement then or adapt to his needs. It should give a good start. He also didn't show the complete list, just part of it.

Comment: I believe those changes are required: https://dotnetfiddle.net/06BIqg

Comment: A low to high variation of `Enumerable.Range` sure seems useful sometimes. I have an `AsEnumerable` extension method on `Range` but perhaps `Enumerable.For` would sometimes be nice.

Comment: @RandRandom: Yes, i think you're right if i read again the "(if has)".

Comment: OP more or less explained it with `(if has)` in the sentence `The list of strings I must create is like this: for each year until 10 plus xp until 100 (if has)` - I am interpreting `(if has)` as not `0`, though OPs datatype should actually be `uint` since neither `xp` nor `skill` should ever get negative, but to much thinking into the OPs mind :)

Comment: As I said, you are to fast, can't even comment fast enough. :)

Comment: @RandRandom: Added it to the answer and also your fiddle-change